# Get a list of Available Functions on Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I currently have a Tampermonkey script with a series of contextualized functions that I provide as options to run when on a certain page.

A simplified version of my code would be:

```
window.func1 = function func1() {...}
window.func2 = function func2(a) {...}
window.func3 = function func3(a, b) {...}
```

I would like to have some function that could take the current script I have and provide me with a list of the available functions, something along the lines of:

```
>> getAvailableFunctions()
<< func1, func2, func3
```

I have been investigating with the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` method, but I can't seem to pull that one out with Tampermonkey.

Can I have some input?

Thank you!

Comment: You'd probably be better off create an object on `window`, then adding your functions to that object. Otherwise, you're going to get all of the functions on `window`, which include things like `alert`, `confirm`, etc.

Comment: Actually I've ended up applying what pswg recommended. Despite having all the objects within window, I could apply a filter to retrieve the specific functions I needed by parsing the insides of each of them  with a .filter( a=> (typeof(a[1] ==="function" &&& a[1].toString().includes("Comment that identifies")))

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Object.entries(window).flatMap(([k, v]) => typeof v === "function" ? k : [])
```

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) gets an array of key-value pairs, and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) here serves as a combined [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This would be equivalent to:

```
Object.entries(window).filter(a => typeof a[1] === "function").map(([k]) => k)
```

You might also try excluding native functions like this (tested on FF and Chrome):

```
Object.entries(window)
  .flatMap(([k, v]) => typeof v === "function" && !/{\s*\[native code]\s*}/.test(v) ? k : [])
```

Comment: It'll list dozens (actually, hundreds in Tampermonkey's sandbox) of standard functions defined in `window`.

Comment: ...even with `[native code]` excluded there'll be dozens of standard irrelevant functions.